# Métodos constructores en Java

Tags: java, constructor

Sobre los **métodos constructores** tengo varias preguntas:

1. ¿Cuál es la finalidad?
2. ¿Qué los diferencia de los métodos normales?
3. ¿Cómo se usan de forma básica?
4. ¿En qué ayudan a un programa en sí?

Comment: Millenians dejándole su tarea a internet.

FACEPALM

Answer (score 1):

Palabras que tenes que buscar:
*Instancia
*Objeto
*Clase
*Encapsulamiento
ej:
una clase persona

```
public class Persona{
 //Atributos encapsulados
 private String nombre;
 private int edad;

 //Constructor puede haber mas de uno pero siempre lleva el mismo nombre 
 //de la clase.
 public Persona(String nom,int ed){
  nombre = nom;
  edad=ed;
  }
 //getters
 public String getNombre(){
 return nombre;
 }
 public int getEdad(){
 return edad;
 }
 public void setNombre(String nom){
  nombre=nom;
 }
 public void setEdad(int ed){
  edad=ed;
 }
}

ahora escribo desde el main


public static void main(String[] args){
//agarro la clase Persona la instancio y la convierto en un objeto, usando el 
//constructor
Persona p1= new Persona("Sergio","35");
//cuando pongo new Persona("Sergio",35); estoy usando el contructor de Persona
//gracias a eso ahora hay en memoria un p1, con los atributos nombre="Sergio"
//y edad = 35.
//Si yo quiero saber que edad tiene p1 le pregunto a getEdad() o si quiero 
//cambiarle la edad uso setEdad(36);
//ejmplo:
System.out.println(p1.getEdad());
//en pantalla dice 35;
p1.setEdad(36);
System.out.println(p1.getEdad());
//en pantalla dice 36;

}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu contribución, ayudanos a responder preguntas que sean basadas en lo que indica el [help]. Recuerda revisar [answer] para mejorar tus respuestas, saludos.